# TextFormField's textAligin argument makes keyboard gets out of work

Tags: dart, flutter

Why when I use the textAligin argument in the TextFormField widget in the following code, the keyboard gets out of work. That's mean I can't set the focus and the keyboard doesn't show.

```
new TextFormField(
    /* textAligin: TextAlign.end, */
    obscureText: obscure,
    style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
    ),
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
        icon: new Icon(
            icon,
            color: Colors.white,
        ),
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: hint,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 30.0, left: 5.0),
    ),
)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what "keyboard gets out of work." means exactly?

Comment: " I can not touch it as an input to write something in it." You mean you can't set the focus and the keyboard doesn't show?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer
yes

Comment: could the `contentPadding` be interfering with the focusable area?